# Bus travel from Salgótarján to Nagymaros on Easter Sunday

Tags: buses, hungary

On Easter Sunday, I would like to travel from Salgótarján to Nagymaros using this connection: https://goo.gl/maps/Nhw68hTq28F2

My question is how realistic it is. I expect that some connections running on regular Sunday won't run because of Easter, there are also some 5 mins. interchanges and I don't know, if buses wait for each other in Hungary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out:

- local tourist information office didn't provide correct info (they told me that I need to travel via Budapest, but I was able to make it via Balassagyarmat just fine (which was my original plan)
- timetable search at http://menetrendek.hu works fine, but it's not available in English, afaik. After some clicking around, it's usable, though. And it has a mobile version, too.

Comment: Can you share what you found using that website? That will help people in the future who find this question and it answer(s) and hope to do a like travel.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/113630)

Comment: @Willeke I've tried to improve the answer, based on my actual travel. Do you find it better now?

Comment: No, not really. Did you manage your travel with the short connections, or did the different route mean that you did not need them? And can you give one sample travel from that time table?

Comment: I added a note that I was able to find connection running my originally planned route (despite info from the tourist office).